# How should I use "play roles", "play many roles" or somethings else?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

If A has an influence on B, one can say A plays a role in B.

If A has no influence on B, one can say A plays no role in B.

What if A has two different influences on B? Should it be: A plays two roles in B?

And what if A has many influences on B? Should it be A plays many roles or play roles?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When I was growing up, it would almost always be *A plays no **part** in B*, and I don't think anyone would have thought it was meaningful to pluralise ***parts*** there. Looking at Google NGraMS, I'm astonished to see [just how decisively people have switched over](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+plays+no+role+in%2Cit+plays+no+part+in&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to *A plays no **role** in B*.

Comment: I'd say the idiom 'plays a role in [the development of immunity, say]' meaning 'is a step in' is partly invariant. Though the literal usage 'plays various roles' is fine and  'plays various roles in the immune system' is an idiomatic broadening, 'plays six roles in the development of immunity'  sounds stretched. I'd rephrase.

Comment: I'd say "A plays a role in B" if the role is single and fixed, or something like "A plays two roles in B" (2 roles simultaneously) or "A plays one of two roles in B" (either of 2 but not both) or "A plays various roles in B" (multiple, unspecified) if there is more than one possible role, depending on the precise relationship. Other forms of expression are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What if A has two different influences on B? Should it be: A plays two roles in B?

I believe in this case you can say both **"A plays a role"** (since the "role" encompasses both "influences" A has on B) and **"A plays two roles"** (to be more specific about what A does).

- And what if A has many influences on B? Should it be A plays many roles or play roles?

Assuming A is singular (a single person, for instance), it should be **"A plays many roles"**. If A were a group of people instead, it would be "A play many roles".